# Cross referencing table of contents and index

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, indexing

I have two separate books, book1 and book2. Book1 contains chapters 1 and 2 and book 2 contains chapters 3 and 4. Is it possible to compile both books so that the table of contents of each lists

chapter 1

chapter 2

chapter 3

chapter 4

even though book 1 only has the first two chapters and book 2 has only the last two? I'd also like the two books to contain the same index. I've looked at the xr package and can use it to cross reference labeled objects, but I don't see how to use it to connect the table of contents and the indexes.